# Find string after "X" date

Tags: string, date, batch-file, find

I have a folder with 300+ text files; I am trying to create a batch script that will find anything after a certain date with the following lines within each text:

---------- \SC####SVR####\E$\USERS\SC####POS####\E2ELOGS\PED_***20141116***_110913.DBG: 1

As indicated date format would be ***YYYYMMDD***

For example:

```
set filedatetime=10/11/2014 12:26
set filedatetime=%filedatetime:~6,4%%filedatetime:~3,2%%filedatetime:~0,2%
echo "%filedatetime%"

FINDSTR "%FILEDATETIME%" C:\RESULTS\*.TXT
```

And if the findstr result is GTR than 20141110 echo the line out to another txt file.

Comment: is the only place where `_` is presented around the date?

Comment: Yes only place where _ exists is presented around the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /a filedatetime=20141124
set sourcedir=
set outfile=E:\outfile.txt

REM There are 3 underscores per record in the input files, creating 4 tokens. The third token (%%c) is the date in the filename.
REM Due to the presence of at least one backup file named "BACK_*", which adds a fourth underscore, we filter that out.

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_" %%a in ('findstr /r ".*_.*_.*" "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
if %%c geq %filedatetime% echo %%a_%%b_%%c_%%d | find /I /V "BACK" >>%outfile%
)

rem type newfile.txt

goto :EOF
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If the date portion of the string is always in the same location, you can simply use the string handling functions to parse it out. At that point, convert it to an integer if necessary, then compare the result with your target date.

Comment: Yes, ALWAYS in the same location.

Comment: What string handling functions are available in the scripting language you use? Look for something that lops off all leading characters before x, and another function that does the same thing for all characters after y, where x and y are the character index parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET filedatetime=20141116
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"

(
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=_" %%a IN ('findstr /r ".*_.*_.*" "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
 IF %%b geq %filedatetime% ECHO %%a_%%b_%%c
)
)>newfile.txt

TYPE newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Produces a new file `newfile.txt`

I used a fixed date for convenience of testing.

`geq` produces lines equal to or greater than the date selected. `gtr` would yield strictly greater than.

---

Here's my test data (I've abbreviated it)

```
-S\PED_20140129_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20140229_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20140329_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20140429_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20140529_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20140629_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20140729_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20140829_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20140929_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20141029_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20141129_110913.DBG: 1 
-S\PED_20141229_110913.DBG: 1
```

And results:

```
U:\sourcedir\t w o\extra.txt:-S\PED_20141129_110913.DBG: 1 
U:\sourcedir\t w o\extra.txt:-S\PED_20141229_110913.DBG: 1
```

I would suggest that the problem is in the filenames section - if underscores appear there, then that an incorrect string would be taken for comparison.

You could test this with (replacement `if` statement)

```
IF %%b geq %filedatetime% ECHO "%%b" geq "%filedatetime%"
```

which would show which strings are being compared.

This should fix that problem:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET filedatetime=20141116
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"

(
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims=:" %%p IN ('findstr /r ".*_.*_.*" "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=_" %%a IN ("%%r") DO (
  IF %%b geq %filedatetime% ECHO %%p:%%q:%%a_%%b_%%c
 )
)
)>newfile.txt

TYPE newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

which separates-out the filename from the data, then processes the data alone.

Comment: This script runs successfully, however, I am receiving dates MUCH prior to the filedatetime.  1 results is

\\Server\Results\Test.TXT:---------- \\Server2\E$\Logs\PED_20140429

As you can see pulling April 29, 2014.

Comment: No matter what the filedatetime is set to I get the same results.